# Change speed (tempo) of playing track in realtime in iOS

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio

I'm after writing an app that is essentially based on a very simple DJ metaphor. I want to be able to change the tempo of a track in real time by adjusting a slider.

Can this be done in realtime using the AVAudioPlayer class, or can you only set it while preparing the track for playback?

Answer (score 0):

Not with the AVAudioPlayer class, but possibly with the new time pitch audio unit using the iOS Audio Unit API to play your track.

Comment: Is this available in iOS now? I can only find MacOS documentation.

Comment: I think hotpaw2 refers to the kAudioUnitSubType_NewTimePitch component subType. It seems to be an upgrade of the older kAudioUnitSubType_TimePitch component subType with some tweaks and it is now available on iOS. Problem is it seems to introduce some issues, as mentioned here: http://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2012/Sep/msg00020.html

I've done some testing and on my device I don't get a monofied stream, as proposed in the thread above, but it does distort the signal in some way. I'll probably post a separate question on that issue...